# how to show id of Div That Is clicked in AlertBox

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I have Multiple div on a page and I am trying to show Id of my Div That is clicked**

> Here Is My HTML Code

```
<div id="div1" class="Mydiv">
    Abcd
</div>
<div id="div2" class="Mydiv">
    EFGH
</div>
<div id="div3">
    IJKL
</div>
```

> Here Is My jQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        debugger;
        alert($(this).attr('id'));        
    })
})
```

but when i execute it it shows undefined in alert box instead of Id
Please Help me.

Comment: Where do you think `this` gets its value in `ready` callback function, and what you expect it to be in `$(this).click(...)` ..?

Comment: `$('div').click(function () {....`

Comment: [Introducing Events | jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-events/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `$(this)` use element or selector. Because in your above code `this` on which you have bind the click event is don't have `id` attribute. Here I have binded the click event on `div` in which there is `id` attribute, similarly you can bind event on other element, class and ids.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('div').click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));        
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="Mydiv">
  Abcd
</div>
<div id="div2" class="Mydiv">
  EFGH
</div>
<div id="div3">
  IJKL
</div>
```

Comment: `this` is not `undefined`. There's no `id` attribute available hence the `undefined` in the alert

Comment: @Andreas I mean  this on which click event is binded. `$(this).click()`

Comment: Me too. `this` won't be `undefined`.

Comment: @Andreas ok I got it. Thank you friend :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$(document).on('click','div', function () {...});` to make it work. Or even `$('div').click(function(){..})` will do. This will add a `click` event on the `div` element and once it is clicked you can get the `id` of that `div` using the `$(this).attr('id')`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click','div', function () {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));        
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="Mydiv">
        Abcd
    </div>
        <div id="div2" class="Mydiv">
        EFGH
    </div>
        <div id="div3">
        IJKL
    </div>
```

Comment: And to be more precise, you add a `click` event *listener* which will call a function (which we usually call the event handler). I know it might seem like a minuscule thing to bring up, but I think it's worth making the distinction between event and event listener. The event will happen no matter if you listen to it or not.

Comment: @AmitSingh you can tick mark the answer if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                $(this).click(function (event) {
                     var source = event.target || event.srcElement; 
                     console.log($(source).attr('id'))
                })
            })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="Mydiv">
        Abcd
    </div>
        <div id="div2" class="Mydiv">
        EFGH
    </div>
        <div id="div3">
        IJKL
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$(document).ready ()` the `this` will represent the `document`. therefore `id` will be undefined (document has no attribute `id`).
you need to add the `click-event-handler` to your `<div>` tags directly. After that you can get the `id` by using `$(this).prop ('id')`. Here is a snippet as example:

```js
$(document).ready (function () {

  //add the event-handler to your div's
  $('div').click (function () {
  
    alert ($(this).prop ('id'));
  
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="Mydiv">
    Abcd
</div>
    <div id="div2" class="Mydiv">
    EFGH
</div>
    <div id="div3">
    IJKL
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('div').on('click' ,function () {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));        
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="Mydiv">
  Abcd
</div>
<div id="div2" class="Mydiv">
  EFGH
</div>
<div id="div3">
  IJKL
</div>
```